# How to reorder the list of example on Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-editor

So here is one example

[image]

I added the last example called **Inserting data with a Model Factory**, but I think it makes more sense that it comes before the "Running a Seeder". Is it possible to reorder that? How is the sequence of examples evaluated?